# Pass data across Hapi JS application

Tags: hapi.js

I want to detect current selected language from a domain (like es.domain.com, de.domain.com) so I need to pass it to all non static route handlers and to all views.

To detect a language I need a request object. But global view context it is possible to update where request object is not accessible (in server.views({})). Also server.bind (to pass data to route handler) works only where request object is not accessible.

Hapi version: 11.1.2

Comment: You should mention which version of hapi you are using in hapi related questions as the framework changes pretty often.

Comment: @arb Hapi version: 11.1.2, added to the question also

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
  if (request.response.variety === 'view') {
    request.response.source.context.lang = request.path;
  }
  reply.continue();
});
```

This will attach a `lang` data point to the context that is being sent into the view. You'll have to extract the lang from the url as `request.path` is probably not what you actually want.

Also, if you look [here](https://github.com/hapijs/vision/blob/master/lib/index.js#L94-L99) you'll see a few pieces of request data is made available to every view via `reply.view()` If the locale/language is available directly in one of those data points, or can be derived from them, you can skip the extension point approach entirely.

Again, this is assuming version 10+ of hapi. If you're using an older version, the extension point method is your best bet.